# how to connect android phone(client) to laptop using only one ip address(static)?

Tags: android

I am doing a android project. I want to connect my client(android phone) using ip address to my laptop(server). I am using ip address of wireless modem(MTS). Each time i reconnect the ip address changes. So how can I keep this ip address constant so that only one ip address can be used for connection via wireless internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

If **client IP is fix** then here's an approach

1)Write a code listening to port in android client
2)In the server, write a client to connect to android port send the server IP to the android

Then you can continue with your normal approach

OR

You can use **UPNP** for your case where upnp server broadcast its info to all the clients in the network.But implementation will be a bit extensive in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The ip-address of your modem is given by your provider and will most likely change everytime you reconnect.

So my answer would be you can´t. This makes the question far off topic, you might wanna take it off.